# RecyclerView doesn't appear on screen

Tags: kotlin, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

The list doesn't display on screen and it doesn't throw any error.
Am I doing something wrong connecting the adapter and layoutmanager?
Whenever I open the fragment it writes the following line: "W/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout" and it doesn't change anything to the fragment.

This is the MainActivity.kt:

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.ListView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val addnewmoviefragment = AddNewMovieFragment()
    val movielistfragment = MovieListFragment()
    val moviedetailsfragment = MovieDetailsFragment()

    private var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
    private var adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieListViewAdapter.ViewHolder>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        replaceFragment(movielistfragment)

        val movies: MutableList<Movies> = initList()

            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

            adapter = MovieListViewAdapter(this, movies)




       val button = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation)
        button.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.ic_movieadd -> replaceFragment(addnewmoviefragment)
                R.id.ic_moviedetails -> replaceFragment(movielistfragment)
            }
            true
        }

        //val submitButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.submitButton)
        //val cancelButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.cancelButton)





    }
    private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        if(fragment!=null){
            val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
            transaction.commit()
        }
    }
    private fun initList(): MutableList<Movies>{
        return mutableListOf(
            Movies(1, "Inception", "Very good movie!", "James Gun", Actors("Simeon")),
            Movies(2, "Extracton", "Extracting!", "Christopher Nolan", Actors("Ivan"))
        )
    }
```

MovieListViewAdapter.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView



class MovieListViewAdapter(val context: Context, val allMovies: MutableList<Movies>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieListViewAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    class ViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        val id: TextView
        val name: TextView
        val description: TextView
        val producer: TextView
        val actors: TextView

        init{

            id = view.findViewById(R.id.movieId)
            name = view.findViewById(R.id.movieNameId)
            description = view.findViewById(R.id.movieDescriptionId)
            producer = view.findViewById(R.id.movieProducerId)
            actors = view.findViewById(R.id.movieActorsId)

        }

    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_row, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentMovie: Movies = allMovies[position]

        holder.id.text = currentMovie.id.toString()
        holder.name.text = currentMovie.name
        holder.description.text = currentMovie.description
        holder.producer.text = currentMovie.producer
        holder.actors.text = currentMovie.actors.toString()


    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return allMovies.size
    }


}
```

MovieListFragment.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView



class MovieListFragment : Fragment() {

    private var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
    private var adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieListViewAdapter.ViewHolder>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


    }


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie_list, container, false)

        return view
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        Toast.makeText(context, "You are viewing the movie list!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


    }



}
```

Movies.kt

```
data class Movies(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val description: String,
    val producer: String,
    val actors: Actors
    ) {
}
```

Actors.kt

```
data class Actors(
    val name: String
){}
```

fragment_movie_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MovieListFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/movieListId"
        android:layout_width="389dp"
        android:layout_height="589dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.246" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

recycler_view_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/indexId"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.045"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.079" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameId"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="620dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.046"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionId"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameId" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/producerId"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/descriptionId" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actorsId"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/producerId" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

From the code, I see that the adapter gets instantiated, but never attached to the recyclerView.
You are just missing the following line in the onViewCreated override in the fragment.

```
findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.movieListId).adapter = adapter
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview